# Error with Date on excel files using libreoffice Linux command to convert xls to xlsx

Tags: excel, linux, libreoffice, iconv

I am trying to convert a big amount of excel files with the Linux command:

```
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx my.xls --headless
```

The issue with my files is the content is in utf-8 but is labeled with utf-16.
Then I need to  edit the file using ***vim*** and and change the label utf-16 to utf-8.

I tried to do this with the Linux command ***iconv*** but I have an error:

```
iconv: my.xls:1:4411966: incomplete character or shift sequence
```

So, I continued doing that manually. When I convert the Excel file xls to xlsx using the Linux command ***libreoffice*** everything works perfect but the dates in the excel file are changed to ***0-1-00***

Does any have an idea what could be happening with the change of the date?